# Insert data based on Where condition in Neo4j

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

I want to insert data based on other `lebel/collection`. I have 2  `lebel/collection` ( **unit, user** ) and they have 1 relation (**Business**) between them, And I want to insert data into `unit` based on their relationship. My cypher query is given below:

```
MATCH (u:Units)<-[:Business]-(s:Users)
WHERE s.id = 'some-user-id'

WITH count(u) as numOfUnit  

// return number of units connected with user
// if numOfUnit is smaller then 2 
// insert/merge new data into Units lebel/collection 
// with relation between them

MERGE ( bu:Units {name:'some-name-01', info:'some-info-01' })
WHERE numOfUnit < 2
ON CREATE SET
  bu.id = '${uuid()}',
  bu.created = '${moment().toISOString()}'
ON MATCH SET
  bu.updated = '${moment().toISOString()}'

WITH bu as bu 

MATCH ( bs:Users {id: 'some-user-id' })
MERGE (bs)-[r:Business]-(bu)

RETURN properties(bu)
```

After running above query, It shown following error:

```
 { Neo4jError: Invalid input 'H': expected 'i/I' (line 10, column 18 
    (offset: 377))
        "       ON CREATE SET"
        ^
           at Neo4jError.Error (native)
           at new Neo4jError (../../../../node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/error.js:76:132)
           at newError (../../../../node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/error.js:66:10)
           at Connection._handleMessage (../../../../node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/internal/connector.js:355:56)
           at Dechunker.Connection._dechunker.onmessage (../../../../node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/internal/connector.js:286:12)
           at Dechunker._onHeader (../../../../node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/internal/chunking.js:246:14)
           at Dechunker.AWAITING_CHUNK (../../../../node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/internal/chunking.js:199:21)
           at Dechunker.write (../../../../node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/internal/chunking.js:257:28)
           at NodeChannel.self._ch.onmessage (../../../../node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/internal/connector.js:259:27)
           at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (../../../../node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/internal/ch-node.js:308:16)
       code: 'Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError',
       name: 'Neo4jError' }
```

Comment: The query does not compile, because `WHERE numOfUnit < 2` should come before the `MERGE`.

Answer (score 2):

The docs about [WHERE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/where/) clause says:

> **WHERE** adds constraints to the patterns in a MATCH or OPTIONAL MATCH
>   clause or filters the results of a **WITH** clause.

That is: `WHERE` cannot be used in conjunction with `MERGE`.

As stated in comments, your query should work putting the `WHERE` condition after the `WITH` clause, because you can use `WHERE` to filter results of a `WITH`.

```
MATCH (u:Units)<-[:Business]-(s:Users)
WHERE s.id = 'some-user-id'

WITH count(u) as numOfUnit  
WHERE numOfUnit < 2

MERGE ( bu:Units {name:'some-name-01', info:'some-info-01' })
ON CREATE SET
    bu.id = '${uuid()}',
    bu.created = '${moment().toISOString()}'
ON MATCH SET
    bu.updated = '${moment().toISOString()}'

WITH bu as bu 

MATCH ( bs:Users {id: 'some-user-id' })
MERGE (bs)-[r:Business]-(bu)

RETURN properties(bu)
```